# Database design normalization elearning portal

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms, dbms

Table : **Class**

Here the `className` is unique

```
classId| className
-------|---------
    1  |  1st Class   
    2  |  2nd Class
    3  |  3rd Class
    4  |  4th Class
```

Table: **Subject**
In the `Subject` table class can have many `subjectName` but a class can have a unique `subjectName`

```
subjectId|classID |subjectName
---------|--------|----------
    1    |    1   | English   
    2    |    1   | Maths
    3    |    1   | Social
    4    |    1   | Sports    
    5    |    2   | English  
    5    |    2   | Maths
    5    |    2   | Social
    5    |    2   | Sports
```

Table: **Lesson**

In the `Lesson` table many lessons can be added to a `subjectID`

```
lessonId |classID | subjectID| lessonName
---------|--------|----------|------------
    1    |  1     |   1      | Lesson 1 -The Art
    2    |  1     |   1      | Lesson 2- The soup
    3    |  1     |   2      | Lesson 1- Algebra 
    4    |  1     |   2      | Lesson 2 - Addittion
```

my question is should i add `classID` in `lesson` table because `classID` is already know because of `subjectID` in `Subject` table.  Is adding `classID` in `Lesson` table is redundancy? is `subjectID` enough in `**lesson**` table? what is the good practise?

Table : **Video**

Similarly i have `Video` table which is related to `lessonID`. a user can add multiple video by selecting lesson.

```
videoId  |lessonId |classId | subjectId| VideoName
---------|-------- |--------|----------| ----------
```

My problem is same here as Lesson table. `videoID` is referenced to `lessonID`. here also should we add `classID` and `subjectID`? because by `lessonID` we can identify `subjectId` from `Subject` table and by `subjectId` we can identify classID from Class table. is adding `classID` and `subjectId` in `video` table is redundancy?

I am asking this question for best practises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redundancy is usually a no-no.  Try to avoid it.

Think of your universe in terms of "Entities".  Model an Entity in a database "table".  Then design the "Relationships" between them.

You seem to have 4 Subjects, not 8.

Consider a many-to-many mapping table between the 4 Classes and the 4 Subjects.

I am not clear on the concept of Lesson, instead let me develop how to think of it:

- How many different Lessons are there?  That is how many rows to have in the `Lessons` table.
- How is a "lesson" related to a "subject and/or a "class".
- For "many-to-many", make another table.
- For "one-to-many", simply have an id in one table for `JOINing` to the other table.

That is, "Relationships" are modeled as many:many or 1:many, as mentioned above.

Once you have done all of that, there is nothing further to do for "normalization".